# Passenger & Nginx, with Passenger Enterprise uses old Nginx (1.12.2), need 1.13.2 or higher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Need to figure out how to update this combo for compliance reasons. PCI needs 1.13.2 or higher. Anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of Passenger's developers answered your question on Passenger Library, but I thought I'd mention it here as well.

Phusion Passenger only ships stable nginx releases, nginx 1.13.* is the "mainline" not the "stable" branch. If you rather want nginx 1.13.* you can download the source code yourself and use `passenger-install-nginx-module` to build the passenger module.